# 'DateTime' has no len()) occurred, with Odoo and Zapier integration

Tags: office365, odoo, zapier, odoo-13

I have the exact same issue when I try to load a appointment from office365 into Odoo. the other way around is no issue... I have done some research on it an noticed that Python is expecting the following: datetime.strptime(datetime_str, 'format'). The format depends on what format you are getting the data in. On this site https://www.journaldev.com/23365/python-string-to-datetime-strptime it is explained how python is expecting the format.

Whenever I try to add in the format in Zapier, this is not having any result on the error, so I think this has to be done somewhere else.

Has someone else been able to use this and what is the date format you have used from the Office365 part? Or how have you overcome this issue? Is this something that has changed in Odoo version13 and is that causing the issue?

I cannot edit the Zapier code since that is all in the background.  The only thing I seem able to do is change the date format, or add in some extra parameters in Zapier.

All help is welcome.

Hereby the full error message:

```
We had trouble sending your test through.
Fault (code object of type 'DateTime' has no len()) occurred. Message: Traceback (most recent call last):
Hide details
Troubleshooting Errors | Common Odoo ERP Self Hosted Problems | Contact Support
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/controllers/rpc.py", line 54, in xmlrpc_1
    response = self._xmlrpc(service)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/controllers/rpc.py", line 43, in _xmlrpc
    result = dispatch_rpc(service, method, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 138, in dispatch_rpc
    result = dispatch(method, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/service/model.py", line 40, in dispatch
    res = fn(db, uid, *params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/service/model.py", line 93, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/service/model.py", line 175, in execute
    res = execute_cr(cr, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/service/model.py", line 164, in execute_cr
    return odoo.api.call_kw(recs, method, args, kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 393, in call_kw
    result = _call_kw_model_create(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 373, in _call_kw_model_create
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "<decorator-gen-148>", line 2, in create
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 322, in _model_create_single
    return create(self, arg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/crm/models/calendar.py", line 50, in create
    event = super(CalendarEvent, self).create(vals)
  File "<decorator-gen-116>", line 2, in create
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 322, in _model_create_single
    return create(self, arg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/calendar/models/calendar.py", line 1581, in create
    values['duration'] = self._get_duration(values['start'], values['stop'])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/calendar/models/calendar.py", line 748, in _get_duration
    diff = fields.Datetime.from_string(stop) - fields.Datetime.from_string(start)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/fields.py", line 1790, in to_datetime
    return datetime.strptime(value, DATETIME_FORMAT[:len(value)-2])
TypeError: object of type 'DateTime' has no len()
```

Comment: Yes a bit more of the error message would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The `DateTime` method does not return a `.len()` property, so calling such will result in an error. The solution to this is to set `DateTime` to a variable, and then call the length of that variable.

Comment: And how can I do that in a Zap?

Comment: Until I get back to my computer, try to find some documentation on setting variables in Zap.